# GParted white windows after 'Sleep mode'

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I had troubles with one of my partitions, so I have booted Ubuntu Live USB,
opened GParted and started *'Check and restore'* for this partition.

The problem is when I went out the room and came back, I saw that my laptop is in *'Sleep mode'* and now I have only white windows in GParted. I hear some noise from hard drive, so seems like operation is continuing.

But I'm afraid because I cant see any buttons or progress in GParted. Also, I cant close this window.

Pls tell me, what should I do? Should I wait? That partition has big capacity (235 Gb), so operation can take a lot of time.

Here is the screenshot:

[image: myWhiteWindowOfGParted]

Comment: Well, I decided to kill this process. Partitions are not changed.

Comment: make sure in your power option to keep your computer awake

Comment: GParted operations are not designed to be resumable. You should keep your computer on until all operations in queue finish. There is rollback for some procedures but it is not preferable because it will try to roll back for every sake.

Comment: @ErkinAlpGüney I waited for 3 hours. And had a lot of work for next day, so I had to risk

Answer (score 1):

As I said the process was killed. And nothing bad happened, huh ;) That partition has NTFS, so I tried to fix it with command `ntfsfix` but it didn't help too. Then I loaded Windows 8 and tried to run `CHKDSK D: /F` in cmd. Finally! That was right solution. But I've lost about 20 Gb of data. Note, this trouble was because of using Acronis Disk Director 11. I tried to move partition. Fortunately, I had a feeling that I should make a backup of the most important files, so that loss was not critical.

Answer (score 0):

Next time. Make sure your PC Stays Plugged in,and that in your power option you configured it to stay awake.

```
go to system settings -> power. Set "Suspend when inactive" to "Don't Suspend"
```